# Errors when extending a base class for CRUD implementation

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to implement a base class in typescript for my node.js application. The idea is that all entities/objects can extend the base class to use for their CRUD.

Here is the base class:

```
export class Base {
    Model: any;
    constructor(modelName: object) {
        this.Model = modelName;

    }
    public getAll(req: Request, res: Response) {
        console.log(this.Model);
        this.Model.find({}, (err: Error, result: any) => {
            if (err) {
                res
                    .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                    .send({
                        message: HttpStatus.getStatusText(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND),
                        error: err
                    });
            }
            res
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .send({
                    message: HttpStatus.getStatusText(HttpStatus.OK),
                    output: result
                });
        });
    }

    public get(params: object, res: Response) {
        this.Model.find(params, (err: Error, result: any) => {
            if (err) {
                res
                    .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                    .send({
                        message: HttpStatus.getStatusText(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND),
                        error: err
                    });
            }
            res
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .send({
                    message: HttpStatus.getStatusText(HttpStatus.OK),
                    output: result
                });
        });
    }

    public create(params: object, res: Response) {
        console.log(this.Model);
        this.Model.create(params, (err: Error, result: any) => {
            if (err) {
                res
                    .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .send({
                        message: HttpStatus.getStatusText(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR),
                        error: err
                    });
            }
            res
                .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                .send({
                    message: HttpStatus.getStatusText(HttpStatus.CREATED),
                    output: result
                });
        });
    }

    public update(params: object, res: Response) {
        this.Model.update(params, (err: Error, result: any) => {
            if (err) {
                res
                    .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .send({
                        message: HttpStatus.getStatusText(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR),
                        error: err
                    });
            }
            res
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .send({
                    message: HttpStatus.getStatusText(HttpStatus.OK),
                    output: result
                });
        });
    }

    public delete(params: object, res: Response) {
        this.Model.delete(params, (err: Error, result: any) => {
            if (err) {
                res
                    .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                    .send({
                        message: HttpStatus.getStatusText(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND),
                        error: err
                    });
            }
            res
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .send({
                    message: HttpStatus.getStatusText(HttpStatus.OK),
                    output: result
                });
        });
    }

    public search(req: Request, res: Response) {

    }

    public filter(req: Request, res: Response) {

    }
}
```

And the child class is as follows:

```
class AssetClass extends Base {
    constructor(model: object) {
        model = AssetClassModel;
        logger.debug("creating the assetClass constructor");
        super(model);
    }

    public get(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const params: object = {
            name: req.body.name
        };
        super.get(params, res);
    }

    public create(req: Request, res: Response) {
        logger.debug("creating the asset class");
        const params: object = {
            name: req.body.name,
            manufacturer: req.body.manufacturer,
            category: req.body.category
        };
        super.create(params, res);
    }

    public update(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const params: object = {
            name: req.body.name,
            manufacturer: req.body.manufacturer,
            category: req.body.category
        };
        super.update(params, res);
    }

    public delete(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const params: object = {
            name: req.body.name,
        };
        super.delete(params, res);
    }
}

export const assetClass: AssetClass = new AssetClass(AssetClassModel);
```

I have defined two routes, create and getAll in my app.ts

```
app.post("/test", assetClass.create);
app.get("/test", assetClass.get);
```

When I test my application, I get the following error:

```
[Node] TypeError: Cannot read property 'Model' of undefined
[Node]     at create (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/dist/controllers/base.controller.js:49:26)
[Node]     at create (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/dist/controllers/assetClass.controller.js:28:15)
[Node]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[Node]     at next (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
[Node]     at Route.dispatch (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
[Node]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[Node]     at /home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
[Node]     at Function.process_params (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
[Node]     at next (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
[Node]     at serveStatic (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:75:16)
[Node]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[Node]     at trim_prefix (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
[Node]     at /home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
[Node]     at Function.process_params (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
[Node]     at next (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
[Node]     at app.use (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/dist/app.js:86:5)
[Node]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[Node]     at trim_prefix (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
[Node]     at /home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
[Node]     at Function.process_params (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
[Node]     at next (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
[Node]     at app.use (/home/hassaan/apollo-be/rest/dist/app.js:71:5)
```

From what I can gather from this error, the this.Model in base class is being invoked through an uninstantiated object of the assetClass class, i.e Model of undefined

But if I console.log the assetClass object in my app.ts file, I can see that it is a valid defined instance.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javacript who `this` is, is decided by the caller, and when you pass in a function to someone, you are passing just the function with no memory of the instance it came from. This is why `this` is `undefined` when `create` is called by the routing engine. To `bind` an instance to a function you need to use the `bind` function or use an arrow function:

```
app.post("/test", assetClass.create.bind(assetClass));
app.get("/test", assetClass.get.bind(assetClass));

// Or
app.post("/test", (req, res) => assetClass.create(req, res));
app.get("/test", (req, res) => assetClass.get(req, res));
```

Comment: Thankyou so much @Titan. You explained `this` very well. Accepting your answer.